# Collapsing divs depending on resolution

Tags: html, css

I've got 6 divs floating rights. I have used percentages for responsiveness, sharing out 33.3% with 3 divs for a row. Worked fine for my laptop resolution - but as I resize the screen both smaller and larger, the divs begin to collapse. Can't seem to find a fix, if anyone can care to explain why this is the case, despite the percentage being a reference to I presume the individual viewport?

```css
.routine-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.routine-content ul li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'amiri';
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.routine {
  max-width: 30.3333333333%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.routine-content h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.routine-content h2 {
  font-family: 'Amaranth';
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.routine span {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.routine-content p {
  font-family: 'amiri';
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="routine-content">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">



    <!-- Monday Routine -->
    <div class="routine monday">
      <h2>Monday</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so your head..
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You can keep your legs on the ground for.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Tuesday Routine -->
    <div class="routine tuesday">
      <h2>Tuesday</h2>


      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so. loor.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't available, try a bent-over row.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You can keep your legs on the ground.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Wednsday Routine -->
    <div class="routine wednesday">
      <h2>Wednesday</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees..
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You can keep your legs on the ground for this one if that feels more comfortable.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Thursday Routine-->
    <div class="routine thursday">
      <h2>Thursday</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so your head, back.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: one if that feels more comfortable.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Friday Routine -->
    <div class="routine friday">
      <h2>Friday</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your. and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so your the bench, your feet flat on the floor.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You .
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Saturday Routine -->
    <div class="routine saturday">
      <h2>Saturday</h2>


      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so. loor.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you, try a bent-over row.
        </li>

        <li>
          <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. You can keep your legs on the ground.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super sure what you mean by collapse, but I think this should solve it. You can have different CSS be activated based on the device width (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)).  I did this below.  So, when the width is below 500px, the workouts will be displayed with only one per row.  Otherwise, there will be three per row as there is currently.  Feel free to toy around with the `max-width` parameter to see what works best.

```css
.routine-content{
    text-align:center;
}
.routine-content ul li{
    display:block;
    line-height:1.1em;
    font-family:'amiri';
    margin-top:10px;

}

.routine{
    max-width:30.3333333333%;
    float:left;
    white-space: normal;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:3%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    vertical-align:top;


}

.routine-content h1{
    font-family:'Pacifico',sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.routine-content h2{
    font-family:'Amaranth';
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:18px;
}

.routine span{
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.routine-content p{
    font-family:'amiri';
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .routine {
      text-align: center;
      max-width:100%;
      display: block;
      float: center;
      clear: both;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class = "routine-content">
 <div class = "inner-wrapper">

 
    <div style="width:100%;">
  <!-- Monday Routine -->
  <div align="center" class = "routine monday">
   <h2 class="workoutheader">Monday</h2>
   <ul>
    <li>
    <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so your head..
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You can keep your legs on the ground for.
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Tuesday Routine -->
  <div align="center" class = "routine tuesday">
   <h2>Tuesday</h2>


   <ul>
    <li>
    <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so. loor.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't available, try a bent-over row.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You can keep your legs on the ground.
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Wednsday Routine -->
  <div align="center" class = "routine wednesday">
   <h2>Wednesday</h2>
   <ul>
    <li>
    <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees..
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You can keep your legs on the ground for this one if that feels more comfortable.
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div align="center" style="width:100%">
  <!-- Thursday Routine-->
  <div class = "routine thursday">
   <h2>Thursday</h2>
   <ul>
    <li>
    <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so your head, back.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: one if that feels more comfortable.
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Friday Routine -->
  <div align="center" class = "routine friday">
   <h2>Friday</h2>
   <ul>
    <li>
    <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your. and don't let your knees go over your toes during this lower-body move.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so your the bench, your feet flat on the floor.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you don't have a bench available, try a bent-over row.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. Quick tip: You .
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Saturday Routine -->
  <div align="center" class = "routine saturday">
   <h2>Saturday</h2>


   <ul>
    <li>
    <span>Bodyweight Squats</span>—15 reps.Quick tip: Get low, keep your chest up, and don't let your.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Bench Press</span>—12 reps. Quick tip: Position yourself so. loor.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Dumbbell Row</span>—12 reps each side. Quick tip: If you, try a bent-over row.
    </li>

    <li>
    <span>Lying Isometric Y</span>,—Hold for 30 seconds. You can keep your legs on the ground.
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response. Though this solution worked, I decided to go rather with 'flex'. It's much simpler than my original approach, and works really well for responsiveness :)

Comment: In fact Dan, having ran your snippet it seems to be react as my original question post. I'll have another look tomorrow morning :)

Comment: Hey James, just wanted to make sure you're aware, the flex property is not supported by IE9 and below, and IE10 and below without the vendor prefix. Depending what your project is for, this may or may not matter to you.

Comment: Glad that I helped!  I edited this to make it work a little bit better.  Should be much more readable space-efficient on smaller resolutions now.